# IP Logs at LinkedIn

Tags: legal, logging

To make a long story short, the CEO in my firm was fired but she did not change her status at LinkedIn about being employed at my firm. I sent her several mail that remained unanswered. So after 9 month I requested a new password (as the LinkedIn account was connected to her previous work e-mail that belongs to my firm) and changed the employment status. That is all I did, and immediately after that I did send her a e-mail explaining what I have done and the new password.

She was not happy about this and made a police complaint with resulted in that I have been prosecuted for hacking somebody elses account.(criminal charge) The whole cases is a big joke. I have of pledged guilty as I have nothing to hide and have explained the reason why I did it (and not used any VPN etc  to cover tracks).

However, now the prosecutor is charging me on two accounts of hacking. According to the IP log they have received from LinkedIn there are two logs from same IP address (mine) with  9 minutes time difference. I have NOT entered that site twice and therefore have not pledged for the second entry log.

How can I prove my innocence? can it be for example that it registers multiple logs when you  switch between programs on computer, or if you remain inactive for a while (for example phone call) and then continue etc..

Any assistance is highly appreciated..

Comment: This sounds like more of a question for law.stackexchange.com rather than infosec.

Comment: Thanks Mrdeep. My questions was more concerning the issue of how IP adresses are logged and if there can be any explanation of the second entry rather than the actual legal issue.

Comment: This is not a big joke. What you did was against the law in many jurisdictions. "How can I prove my innocence?" Of what? How does LinkedIn log IP addresses? We do not know, that's a question for LinkedIn. You also appear to be missing some information about the "log". What do you mean by "your" IP address? Do you mean to say that there were 2 instances of someone logging into the person's account from your home IP address 9 minutes apart?

Comment: Here's what you *could* have done: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/remove-employees-linkedin-54982.html

Comment: By the way, if you are in Europe, the person might also follow up with a GDPR violation and place civil suits against you and/or your company for mis-use of their email and personal information. If that person thinks of it.

Comment: it's crazy that this person doesn't *know* they just did something highly illegal, and yet they work in IT... smh

Comment: Not necessarily. Some companies have policies that extend the notion of logical resource ownership from company email and the use of company resources to accounts on third party services that use company email for identity. This is how many third party SAAS services work, and is a natural and necessary custodial practice. With this policy, the linked account you interacted with would not be your former CEOs personal account, instead was custody of your company, and you are free to do whatever you want with it, including modify or delete. So, check your policies.

Comment: Just like you don't use personal for company biz, do not use company email for ANY personal business, ever.

Answer (score 2):

> My questions was more concerning the issue of how IP adresses are logged and if there can be any explanation of the second entry rather than the actual legal issue.

I assume that LinkedIn is using web server logs. Something like :

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /example" 401 12846
```

Why two accesses? Well so many options, they may not be differentiating based on who is logged in, did you edit and then verify the change before logging out? 9 Minutes does not seem long to log in, change password and update the profile.